# Excel VBA Link format

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry, I'm a geezer, my last code was something called fortran 2.

So when I run this, why do the last two options put the link into the cell, whilst the R1C1 method enter the value? I have the same problem if I use ActiveCell.Formula:

```
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For n = 1 To 1    ' Sheet #
    i = n + 2
    Sheets(n).Select
    Range("B26").Select
    'ActiveCell.Value = "=[WeeksCountLinked.xlsx]Mr1!R3C15"
    ActiveCell.Value = "=[WeeksCountLinked.xlsx]Mr1!Cells.(15,i)"
    'ActiveCell.Value = "=[WeeksCountLinked.xlsx]Mr1!Cells.($O$3)"

Next n
```

Comment: Can you please format your code properly, using for instance this [help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)?

Answer (score 1):

`Cells` is a VBA property, not used in formulas.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "='[WeeksCountLinked.xlsx]Mr1'!$o$3"
```

for example, or:

```
ActiveCell.Value = "=[WeeksCountLinked.xlsx]Mr1!" & Cells.(15,i).Address
```